# Android: How do I keep SlidingDrawer from centering my handle?

Tags: android, layout, slidingdrawer

I want to specify my own custom layout for the drawer handle, but it keeps centering it, and I don't want it centered!

Comment: What is your "own custom layout for the drawer handle"? Knowing that may make it easier for us to suggest options.

Comment: My sliding drawer is on the side of the screen, not top/bottom. I have a tab, like the one on the G1, that I want at the top, and it has a rounded edge that I want at the bottom. I was using a nine patch image that was stretching vertically on one pixel, to acheive the tab at top, and rounded bottom. The problem is, the thin edge of the drawer is clickable, so I want to separate the image into a tab, and the edge of the drawer so that only the tab is clickable.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Depending on the type of `View` you're using for the handle, you might look to the `android:layout_gravity` and `android:gravity` attributes to position it correctly.